# C scanf ignored when invalid input

Tags: c, scanf

I wrote this code, and all it meant to do is input ints until a negative is entered:

```
int result = 0, input_number = 0;
while(input_number >= 0){
    printf("Please enter students IDs(negetive to stop)= ");
    result = scanf("%d", &input_number);

    if(result != 1){
        printf("Invalid input! try again...\n");
        continue;
    }
}
```

When the input is an int- everything works fine,

But when entering a char (any char the is not int),

The loop becomes endlessly and scanf doesn't request any input anymore.

DO NOT suggest I use a replacement for scanf cause it's a work for school,
and scanf must be used.

After entering char output:

```
Please enter students IDs(negetive to stop)= 4
Please enter students IDs(negetive to stop)= 5
Please enter students IDs(negetive to stop)= r
Please enter students IDs(negetive to stop)= Invalid input! try again...
Please enter students IDs(negetive to stop)= Invalid input! try again...
Please enter students IDs(negetive to stop)= Invalid input! try again...
Please enter students IDs(negetive to stop)= Invalid input! try again...
Please enter students IDs(negetive to stop)= Invalid input! try again...
Please enter students IDs(negetive to stop)= Invalid input! try again...
...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c

Comment: `continue;` --> `scanf("%*[^\n]"); continue;`

Comment: Marc- I did try fflush, it did no effect; Thanks BLUEPIXY! worked!

Answer (score 0):

Read a string, %s is format specifier, then convert to an int in your code. atoi() (or strtol() if you are C++)  will work.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/  (C or C++)

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/ (C++)